# AppleScript: delay between shell scripts

Tags: shell, applescript, delay, scp, mkdir

I try to do something this:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p " & workingDir & userName

do shell script "/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p " & userPass & " scp -pr " & userName & "@localhost:\"/Users/" & userName & "/Desktop/*\" " & workingDir & userName
```

The script creates folder on my Mac and then copies data from remote Mac to this folder

And I get this error: `error "packet_write_wait: Connection to ::1 port 22: Broken pipe" number 1`

But if I set `delay 10` between two lines, it works fine.

So my question, how can I solve it in elegant way without delay?

By the way, I already tried:

1. A solution with `set thePID to` and `repeat until`. It didn't help
2. Set two line in the one line with `&&` symbol (also with `;` symbol). It didn't help:

`do shell script "/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p " & userPass & " && rsync
-r " & userName & "@localhost:\"/Users/" & userName & "/Desktop*\" " & workingDir & userName`

I tend to think that problem not in two commands in one, BUT AppleScript doesn't allow to long command to finish its activity...

Comment: I already tried with ";" and it didn't worked. I checked "&&" also didn't work

Comment: I'm curious why you think adding a `delay` line is inelegant. I mean, you could use the unix `sleep` function instead, and concatenate the shell script into one line. Would that be better? The only other thing that comes to mind is to change the second DSS so that you `cd` into the working directory first and use a relative path. the `cd` command should make sure that the directory is ready for use, obviating any delay.

Comment: I changed my code (2 lines of script mkdir + scp) to something this:   
                                             
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/sshpass -p " & userPass & " rsync -r " & userName & "@localhost:\"/Users/" & userName & “/Desktop/*\" " & workingDir & userName

And this still happens. I think AppleScript closes DSS before this line finishes.